# TDD - Check method correctness in a different way than the one used in implementation

Tags: java, testing, tdd

I'm trying to get out of a situation that happens to me quite often when I write tests.

An example scenario is this: I have this class `Vagrant` that abstracts a Vagrant virtual machine I have configured (`Vagrantfile`) in the project's root. In this really simple case, this class only has a method `start()` and a method `isRunning()` or perhaps `getStatus()`, it doesn't make any difference.

The test should go like this:

```
@Test
public void daemonIsSuccessfullyInstalled()
{
    Vagrant vm = new Vagrant();
    vm.start();

    // todo: here I want to test that the Vagrant vm is actually running.

    assertTrue(vm.isRunning());
    // or
    assertEquals(vm.getStatus(), "running");
}
```

After firing up the VM with `vm.start()`, I want to check if the vm is actually running. To do this I could simply run `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("vagrant status")` and parse the output with a regular expression to extract the status.

However, this is what I plan to do in the implementation of the method `getStatus()` or `isRunning()`. But, does it make sense to use this same technique inside the test to check the `start()` method's correctness?

In other words, my problem is that I'm going to use the same code (or the same logic, regardless of the actual code used to implement it) to check if the method `start()` works correctly, as the one I use to implement the method `isRunning()`. And now how should I check that this code is correct? Should I be confident that this logic is correct, which is to say that I should give up testing some methods, assuming them as correct instead?

Or, should I struggle to find another, decoupled, way to check that the VM is running (perhaps looking into `ps` or something), to avoid using the same code in the test and in the implementation? That would seem to me like writing a method that computes sums using the `+` operator, and then checking that the output of the method is correct using the same `+` operator. What if the `+` operator is bugged?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: Forgot to mention what the test title is referring to. I want to test that a daemon program is correctly started at system startup, inside the vm, and the "vm is started" test in my view should have been only a little side-test, but it gave birth to the question. By the way, maybe I should have used a different name for the test method inside this specific question. Also, thanks to Carl Manaster for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

People who start to work using TDD principle often encounter this issue.

This problem occurs when testing stuff like yours (executing stuff, runtime specific), establishing a database connection, or most often: file i/o.

But the real problem is not how to test this, it is THAT you test these methods.

Unit Tests are meant to run fast. Very fast. The should be system independet and shouldn't perform ANY i/o operations!

Unit Tests should test algorithms, data processing, etc and should NOT perform i/o.

But you may wonder how to test i/o operations then? Not with unit tests but integration tests - but this is a story on its own.

However you should test your `Vagrant` class, but not *your* `Vagrant` class, confusing but bear with me!

Your `Vagrant` class should be like a proxy. It handles the vm and commands to send to the runtime. Bur should not send them! To send them your `Vagrant` class could use a dedicated class, like `CommandRunner`. This class should be injectable (Keyword: DependencyInjection). Which also means that `CommandRunner` should be an interface (isn't required, but will make things easier!) and the basic implementation could `UnixCommandRunner` (you see that this allows to run commands on windows machines as well!)

This allows you to mock (google that, if you have not heard of this before), which is basically swapping a real `CommandRunner` with one, which does nothing (except to log calls to its method, etc.). But you can check, that the command has run, by having the `MockCommandRunner` storing method calls, which you can retrieve in your tests!

I hope this gives you a basic idea, on how to handle i/o stuff in unit tests!

Comment: Thanks, this is really clear! Actually, I knew that this was an integration test, and not a unit one, my description wasn't precise. Also, I see how you decouple the `Vagrant` class from the responsibility of actually running any command, and this fits well with the purpouse of unit-testing that class. What's happening, in the end, is that I'm trusting the correctness of `CommandRunner`, which I'm definitely testing somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you're really testing, what you're really trying to test.  The test name can be very helpful.  You call this "daemonIsSuccessfullyInstalled", but you are trying to test that, after starting, its status is "running".  Try to name your test methods starting with "should": "shouldBeRunningWhenStarted", maybe.  In terms of implementation - you're not testing how `isRunning()` is implemented, just that it returns true after the object starts.  Simplest possible implementation ([simplest thing that could possibly work](http://www.xprogramming.com/Practices/PracSimplest.html)): `return true;`.  Now, you know that's not really working, so you need to exercise it a bit more.  Maybe put an assertion before calling `start` that ensures it's not already running.

You're not really testing what `isRunning` does.  You might want to, as a separate unit test, and that test might incorporate mocks.  This test is just about the interaction between `start` and `isRunning'.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I fixed that misleading method name..the question is actually about how to test that the vm is started. Regarding your suggestion about testing that the vm is not running before the `start()`, doesn't this raise again the same problem? Is it enough that `isRunning()` returns `false` before `start()` and `true` after, to ensure that `start()` works as espected? Doesn't this simply move the problem inside how `isRunning()` works? (Maybe this is precisely what you're talking about in the last paragraph... :D In this case, my problem has become how to test that method.)

Comment: Yes, that's what the last paragraph is about.  What would help you know that `isRunning` is working?  Phrase that as "should..."  Then write the test!